# How to call AWS Simple Work Flow (SWF) from API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-swf, aws-step-functions

I am designing a workflow which should get call from API gateway as it is a platform service and all user authentication and API auth is handled by API gateway, I first considered using step function but throttling limit is just 2 per second which is not enough for my use case. Now I am considering to use Simple Work Flow where throttling limit is much better but I couldn't find any document showing API gateway can directly call SWF like Stpe function . What is the best way to call SWF StartWorkflowExecution via API gateway given that SWF supports HTTP Requests?

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to write a Lambda function using AWS SWF SDK (e.g [JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SWF.html)) to start the execution using `startWorkflowExecution`.

Comment: So you are saying , Create Lambda function using SWF SDK and configure API Gateway for that Lambda function which can get trigger by Rest API call to API Gateway ?

Comment: Yes. Write swf trigger in a lambda function

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use API gateway proxy integration type for AWS service (see the image below).

[image]

If you are not passing the request payload in the format required for the startworkflow execution api call make sure to map to it using the api gateway [Integration Request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-console.html)